# Displaying image in PHP mail function

Tags: php, email, web

I am trying to add the image in the PHP `mail()` function, but, for some reason, it is not displaying the image.

```
if ($_SESSION["code"] == $captcha) {

    $to = $email;
    $subject = 'Details';

    $message = '<image/logo" alt="Website logo" />';
    $message .= '<p>Hi ' . $fname . ', We are xyz xyz xyz n ' . $date . 
                '. <br> We have you booked in for ' . $noofguests . ' people.</p>
                <p>If you have any questions or special requests please fees or special requests please fees or special requests please feel free to <a href="http://google.com">us</a>.</p>
                <p>Thank you.</p>
                ';

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```

Comment: What is the `<image/logo>` tag? That's a new one. I always use `<img>`

Comment: I had a co worker that use to think he could make up his own tags.

Comment: 1.  You dont have an <img> tag anywhere.  2. No src set.  3. What the hell is <image/logo>??

Answer (score 1):

Change this.

```
$message = '<image/logo" alt="Website logo" />';
```

To something like this..

```
$message = '<img src="http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourlogo.png" alt="Website logo" />'; // Replace the src with your actual URL to the file
```

Replace the src with the URL to your actual logo image.  Whatever that may be.

Comment: pointing to a local file in an email is not going to get you far

Comment: Hence why I said replace it with your actual file.  Or should I assume he probably doesn't know that?

Comment: actual file and full site URI

Answer (score 1):

The `<image/logo` tag doesn't exist.

```
$message = '<image/logo" alt="Website logo" />';
```

You'll need to use `<img src` tag:

```
$message = '<img src="http://example.com/logo.png" alt="Website logo" />';
```

- Change `example.com` to your actual website.

Also, `logo.png` will not be shown in the actual email; you'll need a absolute path, e.g. `http://example.com/logo.png`.